# Radio group, jQuery next method is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a validation. in the validation function I added the event listeners and when focus out if the value is not provide to show error.

all are working fine apart from radio graoup.

here is my html (expert)

```
             <label>
                <span class="label">Select Gender</span>
                Male<input name="gender[]"  type="radio"/> 

                    Female<input name="gender[]"  type="radio"/>
                    <span class="error">Gender Required</span>
                </label>
                <label>
                <span class="label">Select a Gender</span> 
                Domestic <input value="domestic" name="trade[]" type="checkbox" /> 
                International <input name="trade[]" value="multination" type="checkbox" />
                <span class="error">Business Level Required</span>
            </label>
```

Js :

```
           case "RADIO" : 
           case "CHECKBOX" : //it works!
                if(actualValue === 'false'){
                    $(target).next('.error').css('display','block');
                } else {
                    $(target).next('.error').css('display','none');
                }
                break;
```

what would be the reason? any one help me?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/68kv5/8/)

Comment: Suggestion: You are scanning the DOM and connecting various event handlers. Use 3 *delegated event handlers* instead. Much cleaner and simpler.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie "Use 3 delegated event handlers instead. Much cleaner and simpler." - do you mean to use only `input focusout change ` - gather? agree. it was added different listeners.

Comment: One for each *set of different elements and events*. I'm putting together an example at the moment for you.

Comment: @3gwebtrain: You can try with `.siblings('.error')` instead of `.next('.error')`. This should work fine.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie - can you tell me a approach on submit to trigger all this error as well?

Comment: Your overall method of applying validation has me somewhat puzzled. I was able to apply my suggestions to the existing code, but it would need to be refactored *again* to allow iterative validation.

Comment: @trueBlueAussie, that not an issue. i would like to build the best.

Comment: Cleaner version added below including full validation on `Submit`. Also noted the original problem you had with the `checked` property. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem was treating `$input.prop('checked')` as a string. It actually returns a bool so you can use it as-is like `!$input.prop('checked')`.

I did a bit of refactoring, as I was a bit confused by the whole event hookup system.

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/68kv5/13/

You will see I reduced the initial event processing to these three delegated events:

```
    this.form.on('input focusout', "input[type=text], textarea", function (e) {
        var params = {
            val: $(this).val(),
            event: event,
            tagName: $(this).prop('type')
        };
        that.errorHandler(params);
    });

    this.form.on('change focusout', "select", function (e) {
        var params = {
            val: $(this).val(),
            event: event,
            tagName: $(this).prop('type')
        };
        that.errorHandler(params);
    });

    this.form.on('change focusout', "input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]", function (e) {
        var params = {
            val: $(this).prop('checked'),
            event: event, 
            tagName: $(this).prop('type')
        };
        that.errorHandler(params);
    });
```

*Obviously please take out any `console.log()` commands I added* :)

### Update: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/68kv5/17/

This one refactors the code a bit, so that only the element in question is passed to the validation.

```
var Validator = function (form) {

    this.form = form;
    this.elements = this.form.find(':input:not(button, input[type=submit])');

    this.validate = function () {

        var that = this;
        this.form.on('input focusout', "input[type=text], textarea", function (e) {
            console.log("that.inputHandler(e)");
            that.errorHandler($(this));
        });

        this.form.on('change focusout', "select", function (e) {
            console.log("that.selectHandler(e)");
            that.errorHandler($(this));
        });

        this.form.on('change focusout', "input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]", function (e) {
            console.log("that.changeHandler(e)");
            that.errorHandler($(this));
        });

        this.form.on('submit', function (e) {
            // todo - add form validation here  
            var allValid = true;
            that.form.find(':input:not(button, input[type=submit])').each(function () {
                if (!that.errorHandler($(this))) {
                    console.log("Invalid");
                    allValid = false;
                }
            });
            if (!allValid) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }

    var that = this;
    this.errorHandler = function ($input) {
        var tagName = $input.prop('type').toUpperCase();
        console.log("errorHandler: tagname = " + tagName);
        switch (tagName) {
            case 'TEXT':
                if (!$input.val().trim()) {
                    $($input).next('.error').css('display', 'block');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $($input).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case "SELECT-ONE":
                if ($input.val() === 'Select') {
                    $($input).next('.error').css('display', 'block');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $($input).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case "RADIO":
            case "CHECKBOX":
                if (!$input.prop('checked')) {
                    $($input).next('.error').css('display', 'block');
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $($input).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

var initiateValidate = function () {
    var form = $('form');
    form.find('*').off();
    var validator = new Validator(form);
    validator.validate();
}

initiateValidate();
```

Comment: works. But when i select female only the validation error go off. other wise the error still show. same way for checkbox too... (i have the rights to select any one right?)

Comment: I didn't say it would be perfect, only better :) Can you explain what the new problem is, step by step, as I do not understand what you mean about "when I select female only". Thanks